# When are routed components initialized?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following route:

```
path: ':id', component: ViewBookPageComponent },
```

And when added it produces the error:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'id' of null
```

I'm not performing a null check in the component since the property will be available when the component is navigated to and in this case the auth guard is also keeping rerouting to `login` prior to any of the book routes being shown.

This is a stacblitz demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-slice-demo-fork-with-id-route?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Findex.ts

If I comment out the route, the error no longer appears, so it seems Angular is instantiating the component prior to it being routed to.

Comment: Not quite sure what kind of routing are you expecting? When an end-user navigates to FindBookPageComponent, how can they go to ViewBookPageComponent?

Comment: Here's a full blown working example that I'm refactoring: https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store

Comment: We first navigate to find, then search, then click on a search result to view the details.  The detailed view would be `/books/:id` where the `:id` value would be used to look up the book.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following fix your problem?

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
       path: 'find',
       component: FindBookPageComponent,
    },
    children:[
      {
          path: 'result',
          component: SearchResultComponent,
       },
       children:[
         {
            path: 'book/:id',
            component: ViewBookPageComponent ,
         }
       ]
    ]

   ]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, wrong implementation. You should put `find/:id` under `children` property of `find` route and then have it `/:id` instead of `find/:id`.

Comment: This is a full blown example with all the routes working.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store

Comment: I'm refactoring that example.  The routes work and the `:id` is correct, as we wish to access a specific book at `/books/:id` and the routing used is relative to the `books` URL and its defined by the books module.

Comment: Hi, @Ole. See my update. Basically, use children routing.

Comment: Hi @Kevin.  Happy new year!  If you study the https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store example, you will see that the routing does actually work.  What I'm wondering is why it does not work in my specific case, since in we have not navigated to `books/:id` yet.

Comment: It's really weird.  I've been playing with the original demo and the route is not activated because the authguard reroutes to login, which should also be the case in my demo, but the component activates for some reason.  Perhaps there is an error somewhere in the module that's causing odd behavior ...

Answer (score 0):

The AuthGuard is not protecting the route.  It needs to be declared within the Book module itself.  See this [question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009560/canactivate-authguard-ignored).