# CanActivate AuthGuard Ignored?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[I'm loading a books module with the following routing configuration (`src/app/index.ts`)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-slice-demo-f2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbooks%2Findex.ts) -- Note that this is a stackblitz link - And it now works by implementing the fix in the answer - to break it remove the authguard from the Books Module routing:

```
{
  path: 'books',
  loadChildren: './books/books.module#BooksModule',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
},
```

The routing in the books module (`src/app/books/index.ts`) looks like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CollectionPageComponent },
];
```

For some reason loading this route switches off the AuthGuard / the CanActivate guard does not trigger.  There is a logging statement inside it tracking when it triggers.

If the route is commented out like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
//{ path: '', component: CollectionPageComponent },
];
```

Then the guard triggers.  Thoughts?

Comment: can you make a stackblitz? off the top of my head something could be overwritten. Additionally make sure you didn't include the same route path twice.

Comment: The link is a Stacblitz ...I put a note next to it now so that it's clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the authguard needs to live inside your `BooksModule` route definition.

```
#in books/index.ts

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: CollectionPageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];
```

you can then remove the canActivate from app/index.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `canActivate` guard with component. If you want guard on your lazy-loaded module, use `canLoad` guard.

Comment: I started learning from angular 4, it has been there since then, not sure if it existed before that. And you've posted some wrong link for demo I guess (you've shared link for "GM’s decline truly began with its quest to turn people into machines", can't relate it to angular)

Comment: OH - Ooops - Thanks for the heads up - This is the right link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/akita-books-store?file=example-app%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts