# Can modules using canLoad be preloaded?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026045/difference-between-angulars-canload-and-canactivate) has this example:

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: 
'app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
}
```

Can the AdminModule still be preloaded / prefetched with the canLoad guard in place?

If not is the only other option to put the `AuthGuard` `canActivate` property on all the routes within the `AdminModule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense, because preloading will happen eagerly when the application is started. So how would your `AuthGuard` know who the user is or what they have access to. It will happen before any services have had a chance to restore a previous session or communicate with anything.

`canLoad` and `canActivate` are asynchronous operations, and preloading is ineffective if it has to *wait* before it can preload.

Ask yourself this question. Do I need the application to change routes to the *admin* section very quickly. If you answer yes, then use `canActivate` and preload but if latency is fine and you want to save on bandwidth then use `canLoad` without preload.

With all that said, it is *not supported* according to the documentation.

> The PreloadAllModules strategy does not load feature areas protected by a CanLoad guard. This is by design.

https://angular.io/guide/router#canload-blocks-preload

Comment: In the ngrx book collection example I was using the AuthGuard to prevent access to the book module prior to the user logging in.  Once they are logged in, they can see their book collection which is stored locally in memory.  So if the `canLoad` guard could be combined with preloading, then the book module would be available as soon as the user logs in.  Thus overall the app loads faster and we have the book module ready to go post login.

Comment: Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009560/canactivate-authguard-ignored

Comment: @Ole oh yeah, I've had that problem too. You can define an empty parent route above the lazy loaded child route, and apply canActivateChild to the parent. This will prevent the loading of the module just to check if it can activate.

Comment: Sweet - I like that solution a LOT!  Thanks and happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

With Angular 7 and above. It could be possible to preload with a guard through a custom [PreloadStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#custom-preloading-strategy)